# Laravel eloquent limit query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-4

I have 3 tables TAble, TableB and TableC.
each one with 1 milion registers.

And i have the Laravel eloquent query.

```
  $list=    TableA::with([
            'TableB',
            'TableC'
        ])
            ->whereIn('field1',['A','B','C'])
            ->where('created_at','>=','2018-01-01') ->orderBy('fieldC', 'ASC')->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get()
            ->take(50) ;
```

TableA  have TableB and TableC mapping this way.

```
public function TableB(){
    return $this->belongsTo('TableB', 'fk_id', 'id');
}

public function TableC(){
  return $this->hasMany('TableC');
}
```

How can i execute this query limiting number of registes in "TableB" and "TableC".
if i use take() it only limits the final result.

Comment: limit() will be a "take" but done by the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do?
If you want to process data in chunks use

```
->chunk(50, function ($data) use ($variable) {
//process
});
```

If you want display data in tables with pages use paginate.